# Applied Mathematics to Neuroscience Transition?

Tags: research-process, graduate-school, mathematics, career-path, psychology

I am currently studying Applied Mathematics in a university in Bangladesh. I have always been deeply interested in psychology and neuroscience. I want to complete my degree in Applied Mathematics and after that I want to do research in Neuroscience/Cognitive science (not in Bangladesh) Is the transition from Applied Mathematics to these fields academically possible ? Without any degrees in psychology or biology?

I want to go abroad from Bangladesh and get involved in these fields.
I would need a scholarship because I can't afford to go abroad all by myself. Is it possible? How should my path be?

Comment: Why not take some basic psychology and biology courses while you are in Bangladesh university ?

Comment: Unfortunately Universities in Bangladesh don't work like that. Once you are admitted in a subject you're stuck with only it's courses. That's actually the problem

Comment: Are you not allowed to sit in the psychology/biology classes ?

Comment: No, I'm not allowed.No ones allowed except for the ones who are having a degree in psychology/biology

Comment: @ShadmanSakib You will likely struggle, then, with the biology portion of these programs; you may need to take remedial classes even if you are admitted. Does your degree at least include courses in Physics, especially electricity/magnetism?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite confident that a background in mathematics will be a solid asset for doing research in neuroscience. Neuroscience is a continuum, ranging from very biology-oriented topics (clinical, experimental, or system neuroscience) to more math and theory-oriented ones (computational and theoretical neuroscience, machine learning). In any case, a strong quantitative and mathematical background will be at least an asset, at most a requirement.

I did my PhD in theoretical neuroscience (context: Western Europe), and everyone in my lab had a bachelor or master degree in physics, mathematics, engineering, or computer sciences. And we were actively collaborating with experimental neuroscientists, who often had background in biology and medicine.

Two recent books will likely offer useful information for you:

- [So you want to be a neuroscientist](http://cup.columbia.edu/book/so-you-want-to-be-a-neuroscientist/9780231190893), by Ashley Juavinett: it nicely introduces the different fields of neuroscience to the layperson and discusses different ways to study neuroscience, although mostly focusing on the US system.
- [The idea of the brain](https://www.hachettebookgroup.com/titles/matthew-cobb/the-idea-of-the-brain/9781541646858/?lens=basic-books), by Matthew Cobb: an history of neuroscience with a special emphasis on the links between neuroscience and theory and machine learning, which might be your jam if you are found of mathematics.